# Error updating to civicrm 5.50.3 / Drupal 7.9

Tags: upgrade, database

Attempting to update Civi to 5.50.3
[Drupal 7.9, updating from 5.47, PHP v7.3, Server version: 5.7.36-39-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)]

Run into PEAR related database update error. Any thoughts/assistance most appreciated.
[image: screenshot at stall]

Full screen text as follows:
Skip to main content
[Error: Convert "is_autorun" to "runner"]
Error Field Error Value
Type    DB_Error
Code    -19
Message DB Error: no such field
Mode    16
UserInfo    UPDATE civicrm_queue SET runner = "task" WHERE is_autorun = 1 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'is_autorun' in 'where clause']
DebugInfo   UPDATE civicrm_queue SET runner = "task" WHERE is_autorun = 1 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'is_autorun' in 'where clause']
PEAR_Exception: DB Error: no such field in /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 922

- DB_Error: DB Error: no such field in unknown on line unknown
  Exception trace

## Function    Location

0   CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))  /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:922
1   PEAR_Error->__construct('DB Error: no suc…', -19, 16, Array, 'UPDATE civicrm_q…')   /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php:997
2   DB_Error->__construct(-19, 16, Array, 'UPDATE civicrm_q…')  /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:575
3   PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), null, -19, 16, Array, 'UPDATE civicrm_q…', 'DB_Error', true)   /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:223
4   PEAR->__call('raiseError', Array)   /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php:1928
5   DB_common->raiseError(-19, null, null, 'UPDATE civicrm_q…', '1054 ** Unknown …')    /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php:936
6   DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()   /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php:406
7   DB_mysqli->simpleQuery('UPDATE civicrm_q…') /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php:1234
8   DB_common->query('UPDATE civicrm_q…')   /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:2696
9   DB_DataObject->_query('UPDATE civicrm_q…')  /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:1829
10  DB_DataObject->query('UPDATE civicrm_q…')   /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:472
11  CRM_Core_DAO->query('UPDATE civicrm_q…', true)  /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1637
12  CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('UPDATE civicrm_q…') /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FiveFortyEight.php:107
13  CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_php_FiveFortyEight::convertAutorun(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))   /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php:73
14  CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))  /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php:215
15  CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(true) /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:36
16  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()    /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php:89
17  CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))    /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:38
18  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()  /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:285
19  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69
20  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36
21  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  /home/everyball/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module:471
22  civicrm_invoke('upgrade', 'queue', 'ajax', 'runNext')   /home/everyball/www/www/includes/menu.inc:527
23  menu_execute_active_handler()   /home/everyball/www/www/index.php:21
24  {main}

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you try to re-run through the 5.48 part of the import and didn't do a complete drop of the database before restoring from backup. Find a pre-5.48 backup, drop the database completely, restore that backup, and then run the upgrade again.

Update: To address the second issue below in comments, what *might* work is:

- drop the database completely
- restore the "corrupted" 5.47 database:
- then do `DROP TABLE civicrm_queue;`
- then do the following, but if your database tables use utf8 instead of utf8mb4 then replace utf8mb4 below with utf8 everywhere. (You can check with something like `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name = 'civicrm_contact';` and look in the collation column.)

```
CREATE TABLE `civicrm_queue` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of the queue',
  `type` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Type of the queue',
  `runner` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name of the task runner',
  `batch_limit` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Maximum number of items in a batch.',
  `lease_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 3600 COMMENT 'When claiming an item (or batch of items) for work, how long should the item(s) be reserved. (Seconds)',
  `retry_limit` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Number of permitted retries. Set to zero (0) to disable.',
  `retry_interval` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Number of seconds to wait before retrying a failed execution.',
  `status` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'active' COMMENT 'Execution status',
  `error` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Fallback behavior for unhandled errors',
  `is_template` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Is this a template configuration (for use by other/future queues)?',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UI_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

- then run the upgrade

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: In April, I attempted an update from 5.44 to 5.48 which failed. At that point I did restore, without dropping the database (as suspected above). At the time, time was limited and I updated to 5.47.4 which has been working. Unfortunately a backup pre that event has been over-written. Dropping the database now and restoring the working 5.47 database still fails suggesting that the corruption is being restored. Any suggestions how I should proceed from here? Ideas gratefully received.

Comment: I'll update the answer since there isn't space to paste here.

Comment: SO helpful. Thank you. Will give it a go.

Comment: This *almost* worked for me. I found that recreating the `civicrm_queue` table still caused the upgrade to fail, whereas just dropping the table and re-running the upgrade did work.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I followed the steps, but I had to disable foreign keys and after re-creating the table civicrm_queue re-enable them by doing:
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; -- disable,
...
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; -- to re-enable them

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/13799)